# Arduino Due Serial garbage

Tags: arduino-due

I have made a custom board based on the Arduino Due but have some problems with the Serial communication with the 16u2 chip.

i have usb connection with the 16u2 chip and was able to load the arduino-due usb serial hex over the usb port. the usb now shows up as arduino com port. now when i try to load a sketch it says No device found on COM12. the SAM chip is erased but it can't load the new sketch.

now when i load a sketch with a simple serial print at 115200 over the native port. the SAM chip is programmed correctly. when i open the serial monitor i receive data but it is garbage! the garbage is always different. the sketch is at 115200 and the monitor also at 115200.

this would explain why it can't upload a sketch with the 16u2.

the same sketch on a original arduino due works fine.

the transmit an receive led are blinking.

What would cause this garbage in the connection where do i start looking?

Comment: SAM chip not running at the speed you expect it to run at?

Comment: Tip: Output a constant stream of "U" through the serial port. Measure the resultant frequency on the TX pin (before it gets to the 16U2). Double the frequency. That is the actual baud rate it's transmitting at. Compare that to what you expect it to be (115200). Any difference can indicate a difference in source clock speed.

Comment: You mean the serial speed or the actual chip speed?

Comment: The actual chip speed determines the serial speed. If that is wrong the serial will be wrong. By analysing the serial speed you can back-track that to the chip clock speed.

Comment: Alright thank you for the tip! will try to messure the frequency of the TX.

Comment: What could cause the chip to run at a wrong speed?
and is there a way to test te speed at what speed a chip is running?

Comment: Incorrect crystal or incorrect fuse settings. Testing the TX is a good way of measuring the clock speed. You get a ratio of what you want and what you measure, then apply that ratio to the clock speed you want - the result is the actual clock speed.

Comment: was not able to get a frequency test but did a speed test sketch on a original Due and 2 of my own builds.
The Due runs at 6745 Millis
and my own at 6281 Millis so it seems to be running slower then the original Due.

the crystal used is:
[link](http://nl.mouser.com/ProductDetail/AVX-Kyocera/CX3225GB16000D0HEQCC/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsBj6bBr9Q9aY2qtJ4G5VulXsepr2xtQ88lx3KdWv5%2fNQ%3d%3d).
i don't have any knowledge of fuse settings so will have to read into this.
if i have a different crystal would this need different fuse settings than a original Due?

Comment: Umm, well according to the schematics the Due has a 12MHz crystal. Yours is 16MHz. And you numbers suggest it's running faster than the original not slower, which would make sense. So yes, you will need to change the fuse settings to get the correct speed from a 16MHz crystal. At the moment you are most likely overclocking it.

Comment: sorry that was the 16U2 crystal it is a 12MHz crystal:
[link](http://nl.mouser.com/ProductDetail/AVX/CX3225GB12000D0HEQCC/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsBj6bBr9Q9aY2qtJ4G5VuluOinto8ZXps5Gek8Esa6yw%3d%3d)

Yes you are correct its the other way it is running faster.

Comment: Have you adjusted the crystal's capacitors to suit the crystal you have chosen?

Comment: I have checked and it seems that they are 12pF and the datasheet for the crystal says it needs a 8pF.
Could this be the solution so my problem?

Comment: The crystal has a load capacitance of 8pf - that means it needs around 16pf load capacitors.

Comment: Oke so replace them with 16pF or is the 12pF close enough?